# C++ implementation for DataGrid

Tags: c#, c++, datagrid, mfc, components

I've noticed that the built in C# DataGrid doesn't have great performance (not good enough for what I'm doing anyway).

Is there a C++ implementation for a DataGrid ?
I need one that hopefully has about the same functinality and a COM interface or something that can be access with managed .NET code.

(If there's nothing with accessability I can wrap it a bit with C++/CLI)

Thanks

Comment: This makes me curious, what are you trying to do that the .NET DataGrid can't do for you?

Comment: More details about your specific requirements and the conditions that cuase / symptoms of the bad performance would make it much easier to answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/datagrid.aspx) or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/DataGridControl.aspx) help in anyways?

Comment: The CGridCtrl (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/gridctrl.aspx) is the best MFC data grid control in terms of completeness and ease-of-use. As for exposing an MFC control to C# / Windows Forms, see here: http://bartjolling.blogspot.com/2008/11/developing-windows-forms-control-using.html

Answer (score 0):

Inherit a new class from `DataGridView` and in its constructor set `DoubleBuffered=true`. Seems counter-intuitive, but works.

Comment: How will that be different than just having it dubble-buffered ? And I doubt double-buffering will actually improve the performance